# Value is Changing from one component to other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new into react and creating a project using react. I have two textboxes with plus button, when i click on plus buttton value is changing on both the components. Here is the code

```
const ProtectionAmountResponsive: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const { saving, setSaving } = useContext(QuotationContext)
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState<string[] | []>([])

const buttonRight = () => {
     const currentPercentage = saving.percentageDevolution;
    const filteredPercentages = filterPercentage(saving.yearSelected);
    const currentIndex = filteredPercentages.findIndex((item:any) => item.value === currentPercentage.toString());

    if (currentIndex !== -1 && currentIndex > 0) {
      const newValue = parseInt(filteredPercentages[currentIndex - 1].value);
      setSaving({ ...saving, percentageDevolution: newValue });
    }
    setIsLeftButtonActive(false);
    setIsrightButtonActive(true)
  }

 <div>{saving.percentageDevolution}</div>
```

// Second

```
const CoverageDevolutionResponsive = () => {
  const { saving, setSaving } = useContext(QuotationContext)
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState<string[] | []>([])

 const buttonRight = () => {
     const currentPercentage = saving.percentageDevolution;
    const filteredPercentages = filterPercentage(saving.yearSelected);
    const currentIndex = filteredPercentages.findIndex((item:any) => item.value === currentPercentage.toString());

    if (currentIndex !== -1 && currentIndex > 0) {
      const newValue = parseInt(filteredPercentages[currentIndex - 1].value);
      setSaving({ ...saving, percentageDevolution: newValue });
    }
    setIsLeftButtonActive(false);
    setIsrightButtonActive(true)
  }

 <div>{saving.percentageDevolution}</div>
```

Comment: It could be because `saving` is coming from the `useContext` and `useContext` shares information across components that are within the same `Context.Provider`? Are you intending to pass `QuotationContext` in both `useContext` calls?  What should be the difference between the two components?

Comment: both components have same functionality, both having two textboxes with plus button and click on button value added into text box @Harrison

Comment: In that case I would refer back to the `useContext` usage being the reason that the state is being shared, I'm not 100% certain you want to use that over a simple `useState`.

Comment: So, what behaviour do you expect?

Comment: @diesel94 : Value should not reflected to other component